# Sticky-kit is not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, sticky

Please connect to this site: http://www.ivexone.com/app_dev.php... when you move scroll bar, the top menu will be fixed in Firefox, but in chrome it does not work.

Can you detect where the  problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this `css` code in your `head` section and this should fix the issue.

```
.sticky .is_stuck{
   z-index: 6;
}
```

Comment: You may accept the answer if that worked :)

Comment: Thanks.. however I had another issue that I don't know if this is related, but this happens in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks.. however I had another issue that I don't know if this is related, but this happens in Firefox. If you connect to http://www.ivexone.com/, then click on "CONTACTO" option, and fianlly scroll down. You will notice that the stuck menu is moved to the bottom of the page.